# External link in WinJS, iframe or not, doesnt matter

Tags: hyperlink, external, store, winjs

I work on a Windows 8 app, and from a page that I use link hystory for running back and forward through the app, I also have 3 or 4 links to external websites(eg: facebook or my site). I tried to run them in iframe, or also to make them open in the default browser like simple links. Both method resulted in an error in base.js that says it can't handle my error (!?) I searched a lot before asking here. I watched msdn sample that works just fine, but if i copy what I need in my app results in the same error. I I use it from another page where I dont have forward history, it works, but i really need it on the front page. Any ideeas? Thank you very much.

LE:

This is my `items.js` code: ( for the items.html page )

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var appViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState;
    var ui = WinJS.UI;

    ui.Pages.define("/pages/items/items.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var listView = element.querySelector(".itemslist").winControl;
            listView.itemDataSource = Data.groups.dataSource;
            listView.itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".itemtemplate");
            listView.oniteminvoked = this._itemInvoked.bind(this);

            this._initializeLayout(listView, Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value);
            listView.element.focus();
            WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", this.linkClickEventHandler, false);
        },

        // This function updates the page layout in response to viewState changes.
        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {
            /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />

            var listView = element.querySelector(".itemslist").winControl;
            if (lastViewState !== viewState) {
                if (lastViewState === appViewState.snapped || viewState === appViewState.snapped) {
                    var handler = function (e) {
                        listView.removeEventListener("contentanimating", handler, false);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    listView.addEventListener("contentanimating", handler, false);
                    var firstVisible = listView.indexOfFirstVisible;
                    this._initializeLayout(listView, viewState);
                    if (firstVisible >= 0 && listView.itemDataSource.list.length > 0) {
                        listView.indexOfFirstVisible = firstVisible;
                    }
                }
            }
        },




        linkClickEventHandler: function (eventInfo) {
            eventInfo.preventDefault();
            var link = eventInfo.target;
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate(link.href);
        },


        // This function updates the ListView with new layouts
        _initializeLayout: function (listView, viewState) {
            /// <param name="listView" value="WinJS.UI.ListView.prototype" />

            if (viewState === appViewState.snapped) {
                listView.layout = new ui.ListLayout();
            } else {
                listView.layout = new ui.GridLayout();
            }
        },

        _itemInvoked: function (args) {
            var groupKey = Data.groups.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex).key;
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/split/split.html", { groupKey: groupKey });
        }
    });
})();
```

And from items.html I have different types of links: some of them links to other application pages, from where I can return with history buttons back/forward and some of them are links to external page. Simple `<a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>`.These links crashes my app with the error that I mentioned below. If I erase the next line:

```
 WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", this.linkClickEventHandler, false);
```

from my js script, external links works, but I dont have anymore history buttons in my others's app pages.

Comment: this is the error i get : Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 4950, column 17 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: WinJS.UI.Fragments.InvalidUri: Unsupported uri for fragment loading. Fragments in the local context can only load from package content or local sources. To load fragments from other sources, use a web context.
The program '[8068] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: and this is the code for the history that makes this error happen: linkClickEventHandler: function (eventInfo) {
            eventInfo.preventDefault();
            var link = eventInfo.target;
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate(link.href);
        },

Comment: if i remove this line `WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", this.linkClickEventHandler, false);`  external links starts to work, but i dont have back/forward anymore :(

Comment: Post some code I can look at - how are you creating your iframe, what specifically are you trying to do here in detail. Can you post a small test case?

Comment: I added the code to look over it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the navigation framework to navigate to an external URI. It's usually meant to be used within the application's local context and pages that can contain 'fragments' to load up into your main nav control.

I wouldn't hook anchor tags with your function call, instead in your linkClickEventHandler I would do the following to only hook your internal links

```
WinJS.Utilities.query(".nav").listen("click", linkClickEventHandler, false);
```

in turn your internal links would be

```
<a href="http://www.bing.com" class="nav">click me</a>
```

This approach only hooks the navigation framework into your internal links. Another approach is to inspect the 'this.href' in your handler and if it contains http:// or https:// then call window.open instead

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much. IT was very usefull.  :D The day is saved :)

Comment: No problem, some overall design guidance and help (plus learning resources) are available too via http://aka.ms/stackbuilder and I have office hours available that can have a larger scope than what we can cover here (check my profile)